# Selenium java webdriver 3: moveToElement not working

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium java webdriver 3: moveToElement not working.

```
WebElement element = ...
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Tried, adding click()

```
WebElement element = ...
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Not working. The mouse is not moved.

Comment: Please provide your html.

Comment: provide html code and locator used.

Comment: Also, If you got any error/exception in the process, post that too.

Comment: It could be that you have loader mask on your page. Try asn explicit wait like:

    ```WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);```
    ```wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)):```

in the least this will verify that the element is there and throw an error if not. Otherwise I do not see any error in your code.

Comment: I just noticed that this is a really old question. I do not know how I get it though.

Comment: It is old. But it is still not working in Chrome/Edge version 101. I can send keys to the element without problem. Need to move the mouse visually before sending keys for video demo.

Answer (score 2):

WebElement abcd = ..........

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.moveToElement(abcd).perform();
```

Above code will work, but please check with the chrome.exe version and the chrome version you are using it your machine. both should be compatible to one another. Check the compatibility with below link.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: Your code is the same as my code. Tried on both Chrome (version 101) and Edge(version 101). I can run tests. So they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `build()` part, `perform()` does it underneath anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("host"));
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

This will work. first check your "find element" method is write or wrong. Please post this step as well. otherwise your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try to find element by xpath rather than link text. it worked for me.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code**

```
public static void mouse_movement(WebDriver driver, String xpathExpression) {
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
    act.moveToElement(target).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: same as my code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to click the element you could try javascript:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with:

```js
const element = await driver.findElement(...)
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
await driver.sleep(500);
```

Comment: Need to move the mouse visually.